# Django-allauth response 302

Tags: django

Всем привет!

Возникает проблема при авторизации с помощью социальных сетей. Ошибка заключается в том, что при переходе по ссылке регистрации/авторизации `http://MYSITE.ru/accounts/vk/login/?method=oauth2`, браузер возвращает ошибку `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Код ошибки `302`.

Проверка на https://bertal.ru дает следующие результаты:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 05 Apr 2018 04:37:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: sessionid=s6ei8nyhxpx0xvl430zjtrsyimwv1l4i; expires=Thu, 19-Apr-2018 04:37:10 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Location: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fyakhshisarova.ru%2Faccounts%2Fvk%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&state=fUNKUiqBxJSy&response_type=code&scope=&client_id=2806261
```

От службы поддержки хостера получил следующий ответ:

> Здравствуйте. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS или циклическая переадресация
>   возникает как правило из-за настроек .htaccess и обработчика ссылок в
>   самой CMS, что посылает клиента по зацикленному кругу. Т.е после
>   нажатия на "разрешить" происходит зацикливание, например передается
>   какой-либо заголовок или срабатывает правило в .htaccess.  Вам нужно
>   на примере ссылки кнопки "разрешить" отследить куда перенаправляется
>   клиент и что обрабатывает данный запрос\переход по ссылке.  Судя по
>   всему клиент переадресовывается снова на эту форму, где он уже
>   авторизован. В данной ситуации вам сможет помочь разработчик
>   веб-приложения.

Данная ошибка повторяется на разных устройствах и браузерах.

Настройки приложения во ВКонтакте (проблема не только с ВКонтакте, но и с Instagram):

[image: Настройки приложения во ВКонтакте]

Настройки приложения на сайте:

[image: Настройки приложения на сайте]

Настройки *.htaccess*:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(static/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(cgi-bin/realestate.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cgi-bin/realestate.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

Настройки *settings.py*:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = SECRET_KEY

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yakhshisarova.ru', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'widget_tweaks',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'realestate.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'realestate.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'HOST': HOST,
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': NAME,
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/httpd/vhosts/yakhshisarova.ru/httpdocs/static'
```

В чем может быть проблема? Как происходят перенаправления внутри приложения allauth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда Вы переадресуете к ВК, то в этом запросе должна содержаться ссылка, по которой нужно перейти в случае успеха авторизации. Код по этой ссылке должен связаться с сервером ВК и запросить данные по токену, который был передан гетом в этой ссылке.

Вы адресуете юзера на http://yakhshisarova.ru/accounts/vk/login/?method=oauth2

Затем сюда https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fyakhshisarova.ru%2Faccounts%2Fvk%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&client_id=2806261&scope=&state=ZS1oaZiEzwzj&response_type=code

Обратная ссылка http://yakhshisarova.ru/accounts/vk/login/callback/ которая у вас все равно отправляет на ВК. Смотри что за код отрабатывает по данному url.(он у вас зачем-то редиректит)

Так же я не вижу у Вас кода обработки урла редиректа, смотри как это делается тут https://vivazzi.ru/it/allauth/

UPD добавить в htaccess флаг QSA к правилу Rewrite.

Также попробуйте убрать http из "Выбранные сайты"

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись. В итоге остается страница https://login.vk.com/?act=grant_access&client_id=2806261&settings=0&redirect_uri=http://yakhshisarova.ru/accounts/vk/login/callback/&response_type=code&group_ids=&token_type=0&v=&state=CY6yGntAtzFb&display=page&ip_h=8ca8d06e8c4b2fb931&hash=1523207163_e43dc8ec642e6c9d20&https=1&notify=1.

Callback добавлен http://yakhshisarova.ru/accounts/vk/login/callback/.

Comment: У вас колбек не работает как надо. Он должен работать с токеном(code).

Меня Вк кидает сюда с токеном.
http://yakhshisarova.ru/accounts/vk/login/callback/?code=77777777777777&state=zT5qoErUBSW8

А Вы меня обратно к нему, ну зачем так)

Comment: Это все django-allauth. Странно, но тоже самое нормально работает на localhost. Ковырять под капотом django-allauth?

Comment: Я сам Django не ковырял, но изрядно намучился с Symfony HWIOAuthBundle